Android Studio Bumblebee Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.1.0', apply: false] was not found
This is another question about this matter from someone who has read almost every stackoverflow posts about this matter (and there are many of them) and yet cannot resolve the issue. Apparently, the build files generated by default by Android Studio seem to be alright, but I changed all of them accordingly to the solutions given in the other posts and nothing has worked for me.
This is, at, the point, my build.gradle file:
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0' apply false
}

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

settings.gradle file:
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "My Application"
include ':app'

gradle.properties file:
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
android.useAndroidX=true
android.nonTransitiveRClass=true

gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file:
#Wed Sep 04 23:34:20 CDT 2024
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME

app/build.gradle file:
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0'
}

android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}

Also, in the File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle, I have Android Studio default JDK set, which is 11 by default, and "using Gradle from 'gradle-wrapper.properties' file". I tried disabling firewall and connecting through VPN, I have not any proxy set.
The error message is always the same
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.1.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.1.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    Google
    MavenRepo

Executing the task with --debug-option returns a very large output, but I realize some links referenced on it, like these, return error 404 when I try to access them. So I was wondering if I am just using an old and no-longer supported version of the Android Gradle Plugin or maybe the Android Studio itself. I would really like to use that one, unless it's strictly neccesary to upgrade it in order to resolve the problem, but in that case I think I could handle better with IntelliJ IDEA Android plugin, but I'm afraid I download it and the problem persists. So, any chance you could help me? Thank you in advance
